# Как парсить OCTET STRING из сертификата X.509

Tags: кодировка, парсер, сертификат

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь распарсить сертификат X.509. Судя по описанию DER-кодирования: "Кодирование простых типов данных (в том числе STRING, OCTET STRING и BIT ARRAY) всегда примитивное" получается, что OCTET STRING должен декодироваться как простой тип. Но, воспользовавшись [онлайн декодером](http://lapo.it/asn1js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вижу, что в некоторых случаях OCTET STRING декодируется как конструктивный тип.

Например информация об использовании ключа выглядит следующим образом:

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER2.5.29.15
    OCTET STRING(1 elem)
      BIT STRING(7 bit) 0000011
```

А идентификатор ключа так:

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.29.14
    OCTET STRING(1 elem)
      OCTET STRING(20 byte) 2887B1A7887FD6DDCB6FA11C0E5AD02E15319DCC
```

Получается OCTET STRING декодируется как простой тип, если он вложен в другой OCTET STRING? Или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ почитав [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280).

Так, например расширения сертификата имеют вид:

```
Extensions ::= SEQUENCE OF Extension
Extension ::= SEQUENCE {
extnId     OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
critical   BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
extnValue  OCTET STRING }
```

Это стандартизированное описание, но сами по себе значения атрибутов расширения могут быть другого формата. В таком случае `extnValue  OCTET STRING` инкапсулирует в себе значение этого типа. Например расширение использования ключа согласно RFC имеет вид:

```
KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
digitalSignature(0),
nonRepudiation(1),
keyEncipherment(2),
dataEncipherment(3),
keyAgreement(4),
keyCertSign(5),
cRLSign(6)
}
```

Соответственно описание этого расширения `extnValue  OCTET STRING` будет содержать в себе `BIT STRING`